# Best way to create a table with named columns in the first row in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-layout

I was looking for some built in functionality in SwiftUI for building a table with named columns in `iOS`. There appears to be a [Table Function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table) but it only works for `macOS`. Would the best way be to use a `LazyVGrid`, build the table up manually with `VStack`s and `HStack`s, or some other solution I'm unaware of here?

I can add code to show what I've tried doing if that helps.

Here's an example of the table described above. How would I create those columns and rows as shown?

[image]

Comment: Do you really want the date and numeric columns centered?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I actually didn’t take that into account but it looks like that’s done automatically by SwiftUI? I was more interested in a building a table than where the elements were positioned in the “cells”. Did you have a suggestion or preference?

Comment: Well numbers should be right-justified and dates and text left-justified as a ground rule

Comment: @JoakimDanielson not helpful. The OP is asking a "how to" question. Function over form. Formatting questions can be addressed once the question has found a solution.